# Knockout click binding not working in iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, mobile-safari

I have a simple button like this:

```
<button data-bind="click: login" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Log in</button>


ko.applyBindings({
    login: (viewModel, event) => {
        // this gets never called
    };
});
```

The click event is working fine in all devices I have tested it. Except iPad 9.3.5 (iPad mini)

Looking for answers I found the following work around: https://makandracards.com/makandra/34753-how-to-fix-ipad-does-not-trigger-click-event-on-some-elements

It did not work for me. Anyway idea of how to fix this?

Note: the jQuery click event is not working either.

Answer (score 1):

You are using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which according to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions) is supported on iOS Safari from version 10 onwards. You can change your code to the following:

```
ko.applyBindings({
    login: function(viewModel, event){
        // this gets never called
    };
});
```

or if your code uses more of the ES6 features, you can consider transpiling your code, e.g. using [babel](https://babeljs.io/), or similar tools.

Comment: I have changed the arrow function and it is still not working. I will try with babel in case something else is interfering.